# sphinx4 : getting null pointer exception at connection manager

Tags: java, sphinx4

> Here i am getting null pointer exception at : ConfigurationManager cm = new
>   ConfigurationManager(url);

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();


    h.setVisible(true);
    try {
        URL url;

        if (args.length > 0)
            url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
        else {
            url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
        }

        System.out.println("Loading...");
        ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);

        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");

        recognizer.allocate();

        if (microphone.startRecording()) {
            System.out.println("Say: Something");

            while (true) {
                String printOnTextArea = null;
                System.out
                        .println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                Result result = recognizer.recognize();

                if (result != null) {
                    String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
```

please let me know how to resolve this.?

> problem is solved as i have put config file in same package of HelloWorld.java 
>   but getting another exception of class not found at Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer"); please tell me how to resolve it.?

Comment: in my directory structure if i am putting xml file in same package then it url is not null and gives full path of helloworld.config.xml but gives me this exception 'code' class not found     !java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model
Problem configuring HelloWorld: Property exception component:'flatLinguist' property:'acousticModel' - component 'wsj' is missing but if i put that file out of that package it gives me null as url.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the error is due to url is null.

if this is case

put the file in your package

give the file path as

`HelloWorld.class.getResource("package-name/helloworld.config.xml");`

or else if you have not defined any package then put the file in src folder.
hope this will work for you.

Comment: ya it work for me but give me another error  at Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer"); which class not found exception how can resolve this.?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException will thrown when no definition for the class with the specified name could be found. make sure the class what you are looking for is present in the specified path and its also case-sensitive.put the correct name of the class like  Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("Recognizer");Hope this will help u..

Comment: when i did according to you , it gives me exception at (null pointer exception) at recognizer.allocate();

Answer (score 0):

All it means that your variable **`url` holds the value `null`**. Since a `new File(...)` won't return `null`, `HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");` does.
Make sure that this resource exists.

Comment: and src file HelloWorld.java is under src/demo.sphinx.helloworld/ while  helloworld.config.xml is under src/

Comment: so according to you helloworld.config.xml where should i put?

Comment: I am not familiar with the tools you use but typically in the `res` or `resource` folder.

Comment: still getting same problem.